# How can I define the annulus of convergence for $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I am thinking about the Laurent series of the function:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z}$$

How could I define its annulus of convergence? Since the singularities are $$z=m\pi, m\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Aren't there infinitely many annulus' of convergence for which I can write a Laurent series. For example, one could be:

$$C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ \pi<\left|z\right|<2\pi\}$$

So, is it possible to have many different annulus' of convergence? Also, could
$$C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ 0<\left|z\right|<\pi\}$$ 
be an annulus of convergence?

Comment: Yes, $f(z)$ can be represented by a Laurent Series on each annulus $n\pi < |z| < (n+1)\pi$ for $n\ge 0$.

Comment: The plural of "annulus" is "annuli" (Latin original) or "annuluses". Pick your favorite! :) BTW, there's a more constructive way to answer your question: you take the partial fraction decomposition of $1/\sin z$, develop the terms belonging to poles inside your annulus in powers of $1/z$, and those outside in powers of $z$, and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{\sin z},z=k\pi\right) = (-1)^k $$
for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, hence $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ has the following [Eisenstein-like-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series):
$$ \frac{1}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{z}+\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m\left(\frac{1}{z-m\pi}+\frac{1}{z+m\pi}\right) $$
with the RHS being a uniformly convergent series over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}$.
Such representation can be easily used to derive the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ over any annulus not enclosing any singularity.

Comment: Feel free to remove if too chatty, but congrats on 200K!

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write, for each $m=0,1,2,\cdots,$
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z}=\frac{(-1)^m}{(z-m\pi)}\cdot\frac{2i(z-m\pi)\cdot e^{i(z-m\pi)}}{e^{2i(z-m\pi)}-1},\quad 0<|z-m\pi|<\pi,
$$ then, by using properties of the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function), one gets
$$
f(z)=\frac{(-1)^m}{(z-m\pi)}+(-1)^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2(2^{2n+1}-1)\cdot B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}(z-m\pi)^{2n+1},\quad 0<|z-m\pi|<\pi.
$$

Comment: I did not know the properties of the Bernoulli numbers but thank you!

Comment: @johnmelon You are welcome.